# How do I setup cerberus to validate against a model based on a SQL database schema?

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

How do I setup cerberus to validate against a model based on a SQL database schema? Specifically is there a way to generate the schema definition of what we are loading data into (e.g. SQL Server database table) without having to manually define it and then use cerberus to validate new data against it's definition?

If anyone has any examples of doing so I'd be grateful!